# scene7 ugc file upload shows file conversion error

Tags: scene7

I am using `adobe scene7`. Every things works good since long time. Suddenly receiving this response when i try to upload image on `scene7 UGC`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<scene7>
    <user_generated_content>
        <response>
            <serviceName>User Generated Content -Images</serviceName>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <operationName>upload</operationName>
            <serviceStatus>FAILED</serviceStatus>
            <errorTitle>Your operation failed with errors.</errorTitle>
            <errorMessage>Error Occured during file conversion.</errorMessage>
        </response>
    </user_generated_content>
</scene7>
```

Does any one have idea about this?

Comment: Since this is  4 years ago. How did you solve this or what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to upload the image to a different folder. I have seen this error when the folder is full. Other options would be to check the file name not to have any special characters or spaces. Also, check the file size.